# react convert day into Date

Tags: reactjs

fetching date from json convert it to seconds then seconds into minute and then minute into hours and then hours into days.
the code is working find, but now as per requirement, just want to convert it into day,
if date is today more then 12 hours then its should show today
after 24 hours show yesterday, and then show the date as 1 Sep, 10 Aug

**json**

```
 "lastActive": "2017-09-08T16:49:35.129Z"
```

**reactJs**

```
   renderActivity(){
    let date = new Date();
    let date_json = new Date(this.data.lastActive);
    let dt_diffMs =(date - date_json);
    let dt_diffMn = Math.floor((dt_diffMs/1000)/60);
    let dt_diffHr = Math.floor(dt_diffMn/60);
    let dt_diffDy = Math.floor(dt_diffHr/24);
    console.log(dt_diffDy);
    if(dt_diffMn < 60 && dt_diffMn > 0){
      return(
        <span>
          min
        </span>
      )
    }else if(dt_diffHr < 24 && dt_diffHr > 0){
      return(
        <span>
          min
        </span>
      )
    }else if(dt_diffDy > 0){
      return(
        dt_diffDy
      )
    }

  }
```

Comment: use moment js, it has lot of function to convert time and date

Comment: is there way, to code it rather to use some dependencies?

Comment: use Date("2017-09-08T16:49:35.129Z") and you will get date string, then do operation as your need